# Video Streaming such as WatchESPN/HBOGo/WatchTNT/etc. will not work

Tags: 16.04, video, flash, video-streaming, hal

For some reason, video streaming services such as WatchESPN and HBOGo will not work. However, youtube videos will play just fine. I have HAL installed and the latest version of flash. I've looked at every answer that has been associated with issues like this but nothing seems to work. I am running on Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS.

Thanks!

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: Google Chrome - but i tried it on firefox too and it has the same issues

Comment: [install the Flash plug-in](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-install-flash.html)

Comment: Sounds like a [DRM](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Flash_DRM_content) problem.